# Cartier divisors of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

[In his notes](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGjun1113public.pdf), Ravi Vakil only defines the notion of an *effective* Cartier divisor.  Furthermore, the [Wikipedia page](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Divisor_(algebraic_geometry)#/Relative_Cartier_divisors) only defines the notion of an effective Cartier divisor for a general scheme.  However, obviously, the notion of a general (not-necessarily-effective) Cartier divisor exists in other contexts (even it seems for algebraic varieties).

Can one define the notion of a (not-necessarily-effective) Cartier divisor for a general scheme, or does only the notion of effective Cartier divisors make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [the stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02AQ).

Let $K^{pre}$ be presheaf defined as follows :  for an open set $U$, let $S_U \subseteq O_X(U)$ be defined as :  $a \in S_U$ iff for all $p \in U$, $a|_p$ is not a zero divisor in $O_{X, p}$. Then, $K^{pre}(U) = S_U^{-1}O_X(U)$.

Let $K$ be its sheafification. Note that there is an injective morphism $O_X \rightarrow K$. Then, take group of units and take quotients. We get this exact sequence:

$$0 \rightarrow O_X^* \rightarrow K^* \rightarrow K^* / O_X^* \rightarrow 0$$

A Cartier divisor is a global section of $K^* / O_X^*$.